# Writing a regex to replace a date pattern

Tags: r, regex, text

I have a pattern in my data that starts with the three letters of a month and one or two digits after that indicates the day of the months.
this is a snapshot of the data

```
 df_new <- data.frame(
   given_info=c('oct12 is given','he received on jan1',
                'lets go on dec12','also feb04 is right'))
 
 df_new %>% select(given_info)
           given_info
1      oct12 is given
2 he received on jan1
3    lets go on dec12
4 also feb04 is right
```

I need to find the regex to catch these and replace them with a term such as `specific time`.
Hence, the outcome of interest would be like:

```
           given_info
1      specific timeis given
2     he received on specific time
3    lets fo on specific time
4    also specific timeis right
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```r
gsub("\\b[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}\\b", "specific time", df_new$given_info)
# [1] "specific time is given"      "he received on jan1"         "lets go on specific time"    "also specific time is right"
```